# How to pass a Swift array to an Objective-C function

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'd like to pass an array of `CGPoint` values to another `Objective-C` function.

**Swift:**

```
var myPoints:[CGPoints]? = [CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)]
ObjCWrapper.callSomething(&myPoints)
```

**Objective-C**

```
+ (void) callSomething: (CGPoint []) points {...}
```

Error I got:

```
Cannot invoke 'callSomething' with an argument list of type 'inout [CGPoint]?)'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you’ve made `myPoints` optional, i.e. `[CGPoint]?` instead of `[CGPoint]`.  From your code snippet, it’s not clear why you’re doing this.  If there’s not a need from the wider context, just drop the `?` and this code should compile.

Note, if `ObjCWrapper.callSomething` is a function you wrote and control, consider making it take a `const CGPoint []` instead if it doesn’t actually need to change the values in the array.  That way, it won’t be `inout` so you won’t need a `&` in front of the `myPoints`, and you could also use it if it’s declared with `let`, i.e.:

```
// no need to give a type, it can be inferred as [CGPoint]
let myPoints = [CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)]
ObjCWrapper.callSomething(myPoints)
```

if you declare it as:

```
+ (void) callSomething: (const CGPoint []) points {...}
```

If on the other hand it really needs to be an optional array for reasons not shown, you’ll have to use some unwrapping technique to get the underlying pointer instead of using the implicit interop support:

```
let myPoints: [CGPoint]? = [CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)]
myPoints?.withUnsafeBufferPointer { buf->Void in
    ObjCWrapper.callSomething(buf.baseAddress)
}
```

or, if you can’t change `callSomething` to take a const array, it gets quite annoying:

```
var myPoints: [CGPoint]? = [CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)]
myPoints?.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
  (inout buf: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer)->Void in
    ObjCWrapper.callSomething(buf.baseAddress)
}
```

Comment: It works. I think this answer should be accepted as correct @coyer

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that. Objective-C NSArrays can only hold Class objects, not scalars like CGPoints. (AnyObject, not Any.) You have to wrap CGPoints in NSValues in order to put them in an NSArray.

Nevermind. I did not notice that the Objective-C code was expecting a C array of CGPoints, so my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Who said anything about NSArray?  This is a regular C array, which will pass just fine using an unsafe pointer.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity, So it is. (A C array of CGPoints.) I'm on my iPad and missed the Objective-C code. Don't you need to explicitly cast the Swift array to an unsafe pointer to pass it to Objective-C as a C array? (I'm still weak on unsafe pointers in Swift)

Comment: Nah, the interop will just do it for you implicitly so long as everything’s set up right.  Though the problem here is it’s an optional, so that won’t work.

Comment: Wow, really? You can exchange swift arrays of scalars with C arrays in your Objective-C code without doing anything special? That's very, very cool. I had no idea.

Comment: Yup.  It'll implicitly convert `String` to a `const char*` too